# Terminal emulator with half block cursor?

Tags: vim, terminal

Is there a terminal emulator which allows half block cursor? The main reason I want this is that in vim when some words are highlighted it's difficult to see where the cursor is:

[image]

In this pic I have set the cursor to appear as an underline in konsole, but still it's not easy to spot it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use a different color for the cursor?

[image: cursor]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am doing right now, I still prefer a half block though, it gives you a hint that the text is highlighted and also the cursor is in the highlighted area.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal emulators generally allow you to change the cursor shape.

See e.g. vim tips [#1622](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes) and [#746](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor).